# React Native Requiring the same image multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got this sort of general question when it comes to requiring images in React Native. I've got this application that uses the same little red x and green check mark for form validation 6-8 times in a single form component. How it stands right now, I have a require in every 'source' prop when used.

Is it best practice to require the image once at the top of the component as a variable and just use the variable 6-8 times instead of the calling require for each one of them?

Comment: It is probably significant overkill for one icon, but if you are using [React Native Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) and have a lot of images used as icons, consider [creating an icon set](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#custom-fonts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, requiring it once at the top is far superior.

But hey, you can go even further.  If this is an icon you need to use across the app, it might be worth making a very very simplistic component that renders this image.  It's easier to reference `<GreenCheck/>` than to require an image and stick it into an img tag repeatedly.

Comment: Perfect. I'm pretty new to web development, having just graduation from a bootcamp, so these little things are very helpful. Thank you!